# SpringBoot Eureka not refresh service status in REST API

Tags: api, netflix-eureka

I enabled pause, restart, shutdown for endpoints

When I use curl post to /pause of service, the status refresh immediately in Eureka home page as DOWN

But the REST API result still shows UP, it will change after few seconds,
Why they are not the same？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka refresh api result in 30s by default and get eventually consist